# Qt How to set different widths to QToolButton with/without menu?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I would like to control the width of QToolButtons with menu drop-downs independently of normal ones (without menu) like in the following example:

[image]

I think it may be done with:

```
QToolButton {
    width: 40px;
}
QToolButton[popupMode="0"],
QToolButton[popupMode="1"],
QToolButton[popupMode="2"] {
    width: 100px;
}
```

But it doesn't work... any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It works for me

```
QToolButton[popupMode="1"] {
   width: 100px;
}
```